# How to get the name of previous page in ZK?

Tags: zk

I have a list page where it has button menu. While i select a record and click on that button menu a new page will be open with the corresponding code from the selected record.

From the opened page's doAfterCompose, how can i get the name of the previous page from where we clicked the button and opened the new page?

Please anyone help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

What you should do (although I haven't seen your code) is to generate an event that passes as a value the previous page number when 'that button menu' is clicked. The event will then be picked up by the event queue together with the passed value.
So inside the method that handles the event generated by the click of the button menu you should add the following:

```
EventQueues.lookup("myqueue", EventQueues.DESKTOP, true)
            .publish(new Event("buttonClicked", null, previousPage));
```

where previousPage is the value passed (an integer for the sake of the example).

Then inside the doAfterCompose() method you extrapolate the data passed:

```
 EventQueues.lookup("myqueue", EventQueues.DESKTOP, true).subscribe(
            new EventListener() {
                public void onEvent(Event evt) {
                    if (evt.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("buttonClicked")) {
                        int thePreviousPage = (int) evt.getData();
.......
```